# Update column value by querying concatenated column values with another table value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as below. The Id column value in both the tables mentioned below is auto-incremented.
**Group**
`+----+-----------+----------------+`
 | `Id |` `GroupId   |`  `GroupName     |`
`+----+-----------+----------------+`
 | `1  |` `10        |` `Grp1@abc.com  |`
 | `2  |` `20        |` `Grp2@abc.com  |`
 | `3  |` `30        |` `Grp3@xyz.com  |`
 | `4  |` `40        |` `Grp4@def.com  |`
 `+----+-----------+----------------+`

**Customer**
`+---+-----------------+------------+----------+---------------+`
 | `Id |` `GroupAliasName |` `Domain    |` `GroupId |` `CustomerName |`
`+---+-----------------+------------+----------+---------------+`
 | `1  |` `Grp1           |` `abc.com   |` `null    |` `Cust1        |`
 | `2  |` `Grp2           |` `abc.com   |` `null    |` `Cust2        |`
 | `3  |` `Grp3           |` `xyz.com   |` `null    |` `Cust3        |`
 | `4  |` `Grp4           |` `def.com   |` `null    |` `Cust4        |`
`+---+-----------------+------------+----------+---------------+`

Now from **Customer** table `'GroupAliasName'` and `'Domain'` when  concatenated as `'GroupAliasName@Domain'` is equivalent to `'GroupName'` in **Group** table.

Using the concatenated value from **Customer** table, I need to pull the `'GroupId'` from the **Group** table and populate the same in **Customer** table's `'GroupId'` as below

**Customer**
`+----+----------------+------------+----------+---------------+`
 | `Id |` `GroupAliasName |` `Domain    |` `GroupId |` `CustomerName |`
`+----+----------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+`
 | `1  |` `Grp1           |` `abc.com   |` `10      |` `Cust1        |`
 | `2  |` `Grp2           |` `abc.com   |` `20      |` `Cust2        |`
 | `3  |` `Grp3           |` `xyz.com   |` `30      |` `Cust3        |`
 | `4  |` `Grp4           |` `def.com   |` `40      |` `Cust4        |`
`+----+----------------+------------+----------+---------------+`

The query which I tried is as below

`UPDATE Customer SET GroupId =
(SELECT GroupId FROM Group G
WHERE GroupName =
  (SELECT CONCAT(GroupAliasName, '@', Domain) AS GroupName
    FROM Customer
    WHERE Domain IS NOT NULL) AND G.GroupName = GroupName);`

But I get error as `'Subquery returns more than 1 row'`.
Please suggest or provide your inputs.

Comment: exactly as the error says: one of you subqueries is returning multiple rows/records of data in a context where only a SINGLE record/row is permitted.  figure out which one, then modify it to return only that one sigle record/row. plus, you cannot use a table as a data source while you're simultaneously changing it. if you want to update `customer`, then look into using update's `join` support instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update customer as cust
inner join `group` grp on  concat(cust.groupaliasname, '@', cust.domain) =  grp.groupname
set cust.groupId = grp.groupId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with somethings like this

```
UPDATE Customer as c
INNER JOIN Group as g on (  CONCAT(c.GroupAliasName, '@', c.Domain) =  g.GroupName)
SET c.GroupId = g.GroupId;
```